# How can I solve a system of 4 equations and 4 unknowns with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a general equation

t=tr+(ts-tr)/(1+(a*h)^n)^(1-1/n)

for (h=0, 1, 2, 3), I have t=2.000, 1.6300, 1.2311, 1.1084. therefor there are 4 equations with 4 unknowns tr, ts, a, n

I used ***"solve"*** function in matlab

```
s=solve('tr+(ts-tr)/(1+(a*0)^n)^(1-1/n)=2','tr+(ts-tr)/(1+(a*1)^n)^(1-1/n)=1.63','tr+(ts-tr)/(1+(a*2)^n)^(1-1/n)=1.2311','tr+(ts-tr)/(1+(a*3)^n)^(1-1/n)=1.1084')
```

and error is

??? Error using ==> mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Singularity [ln];

during evaluation of 'numeric::fsolve'

Error in ==> sym.sym>sym.mupadmexnout at 2018
        out = mupadmex(fcn,args{:});

Error in ==> solve at 76
[symvars,R] = mupadmexnout('symobj::solvefull',eqns,vars);

What should I do?

Comment: Could you give the full code that you use? I believe something is still missing. Furthermore, is it possible that your problem doesn't have a solution, or has infinitely many solutions? Perhaps start with 1 equation and 1 variable, and work up from there.

Comment: I solved 3 eqs. with solve function. Actually, that's the whole code until now. I solved a+b=2, a+b=3 with this function and after that 3 equations and then this. I know tr=1; ts=2; n=3; a=1 is an answer and maybe It has more than one answer probably infinite answers.

Comment: Why don't you try to numerically compute the unknowns, by the way your code looks correct.

Comment: Are your variable real? Are they non-negative or greater than zeros or integers? Are there are limits or assumptions? In solving such systems it can help to learn about Matlab's/MuPAD's [`assumptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions-for-symbolic-objects.html) capabilities – assuming that you're not using an ancient version. But even these are no guarantee.

Comment: Have you look to the `\ operator` ?, if your systeme is Ax = B you can to A\B = x. Have a look to [mldivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears with you using the `solve` function.  That only works for simple equations, it is better to use the `fsolve` function.  Due to the fact that I am worried that I am doing an assignment for you, I am only going to show you how to do another example using `fsolve`.

Suppose that you want to solve

```
 1 = x_1
 1 = x_1 + x_2
-1 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3
-1 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4
```

then what you firstly need to do is write these as equations equal 0

```
 0 = x_1 - 1
 0 = x_1 + x_2 - 1
 0 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + 1
 0 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + 1
```

then you need to write a function that takes in a vector `x`, the components of `x` will represent `x_1`, `x_2`, `x_3` and `x_4`.  The output of the function will also be a vector whose components should the outputs of the Right hand side of the above equations (see the function `fun` below).  This function is going to be called by `fSolve` for it to provide it with guesses of the correct value of `x`, until it guess correct.  When never actually run this function ourselves.  That is why it is below the top function.

Then you create a function handle to this function by `fHandle = @fun`.  You can think of `fHandle` as another name for `fun`, when we calculate `fHandle([1; 2; 3; 4])` this is the same as calculating `fun([1; 2; 3; 4])`.  After this you make an initial guess of the correct vector `x`, say we chose `xGuess = [1; 1; 1; 1]`.  Finally we pass fHandle and xGuess to `fSolve`.

Here is the code

```
function Solve4Eq4Unknown()
fHandle = @fun;
xGuess = ones(4,1);
xSolution = fsolve(fHandle, xGuess)
end

function y = fun(x)
y = zeros(4,1); % This step is not necessary, but it is effecient
y(1) = x(1) - 1;
y(2) = x(1) + x(2) - 1;
y(3) = x(1) + x(2) + x(3) + 1;
y(4) = x(1) + x(2) + x(3) + x(4) + 1;
end
```